# iOS application slows down on real device

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, cocoa

I have iOS 6 application that consists of UIView with many UIButtons (like 9 to as many as 100) displayed at same time; all buttons are movable, so I'm changing button's frame property all the time.

After using the application for a couple of minutes (= moving buttons around the parent UIView), app slows down. It is very strange also that it seems buttons that are near the bottom of the screen (= parent UIView) are much slower than those on the top of screen.

All buttons belong to same class, inherited from generic UIButton.

It happens only on real device, not iPhone simulator.

Any idea about the issue? I'm using NSlog frequently through the code. Can this be the problem?

Thx,
DJ

Comment: SEEMS to be a memory issue, need to see how you manage your buttons?

Comment: Did you check for memory leaks or zombie objects with instruments?

Comment: for avoiding the performance issues, try to use the `-setCenter:` instead of the `-setFrame:`, because this method is extreme slow, it sets the size of the object in every case.

Comment: Also, you say "I'm changing button's frame property all the time", how are you determining time? Are you only updating the button being pushed around or updating the position of all buttons based on some timer?

Comment: @ahwulf: I'm changing button's frame when the user touches the button.

Comment: @holex: thank you for this, I've changed it from -setFrame to -setCenter as you've suggested; in addition to "switching off" NSLog in RELEASE I also clear now every UIView that I've added but is not used any more. Now, it seems it runs OK.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your NSLogs to be only in DEBUG mode, it will be much faster in Relese:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  NSLog(@"log");
#endif
```

Comment: It seems I managed to "repair" it by using NSLog only in DEBUG mode (not RELEASE). I've also found that when moving from one screen to another I didn't remove previously added subviews (UIViews that contain my buttons). I now also remove all previously added subviews... and it runs faster.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right.

Never give NSLog or DLog in release versions..

remove all nslog, or for testing purpose just comment them out.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  NSLog(@"log");
#endif
```

or

```
#define NSLog //NSLog
```

Also you should check for zombies and memory leaks.